# perl parsing command line arguments

Tags: perl

i have a network and i want to assign all ip addresses a name. For this purpose i want to make a perl script that will print each ip on separate line from an ip range. I found a way via Net:IP but i can't figure out how to parse my command line ip range to the script (i am new with perl). My script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Net::IP;
my $test=join(' ',@ARGV);
my $ip = new Net::IP ('$test') || die;
do {
    print $ip->ip(), "\n";
} while (++$ip);

exit;
```

So my only problem is that the comand line syntax looks like this: perl ip.pl 192.168.10.1 - 192.168.10.255 and i can;t figure out how to parse this argument into my script after Net:IP (' here   ').

Thanks for every idea.

Comment: `my $test = join(' ', @ARGV); "$test";` can also be written as `"@ARGV"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
my $ip = new Net::IP ('$test') || die;
```

to

```
my $ip = new Net::IP ($test) || die;
```

Single quotes will not evaluate your scalar.

Also, always

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```